# Oracle 11g ORA-13226: interface not supported without a spatial index

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, spatial-index

I am trying to run this query:

```
select count (st.STANDID) as "stand view"
from STANDT st
where mdsys.sdo_filter(st.STANDGEOM,
mdsts.sdo_geometry(2003,null,null,
mdsys.sdo_elem_info_array(1,3,3),
mdsys.sdo_ordinate_array(0,0,20,20)),
'querytype=window') = 'TRUE';
```

On this table:

```
create table StandT(
StandId number constraint StandId primary key,
StandGeom mdsys.sdo_geometry,
StandName varchar2(20)
);
```

And i am getting this error:

```
Error report -
ORA-13226: interface not supported without a spatial index
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MD", line 1723
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MDERR", line 8
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_3GL", line 1224
```

As message tells me, i am trying to create spatial index:

```
create index f_ind_STANDT on STANDT(STANDGEOM)
indextype is mdsys.spatial_index
parameters('sdo_level=4, sdo_numtiles=4');
```

And then i am getting this error:

```
Error report -
ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-13249: internal error in Spatial index: [mdidxrbd]
ORA-13249: Error in Spatial index: index build failed
ORA-13206: internal error [Tessellate] while creating the spatial index
ORA-13249: Error in spatial index: [mdpridxtessellate]
ORA-13200: internal error [ROWID:AAAVM/AABAAAXLZAAA] in spatial indexing.
ORA-13019: coordinates out of bounds
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_INDEX_METHOD_10I", line 10
29855. 00000 -  "error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine"
*Cause:    Failed to successfully execute the ODCIIndexCreate routine.
*Action:   Check to see if the routine has been coded correctly.
```

However it is now visible in the `ALL_INDEXES` table:

```
SELECT INDEX_NAME FROM ALL_INDEXES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'STANDT';
```

[image]

Does anybody know, how can i fix these errors to make my query work?

Comment: look at the 4th row on your first sql mds`t`s.sdo_geometry(2003,null,null, , first problem seems here with a `t` instead of `y`

Comment: secondly, is your schema granted for `USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA`? whenever you're granted, drop and recreate your index.